# How do I reliably get a value for HEAD that I can checkout again?

Tags: git, branch, git-detached-head

My Git repository is in a state where `HEAD` might be a branch, or it might be a *detached head*. In a script, I want to get the current value such that I can reliably restore it with `git checkout` later: that is, if we're on a branch now, I want to come back to that branch, not to a detached head of that commit. What's the easiest way to get that information, without having to deal with the two cases separately in my script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD || git show-ref -s HEAD
```

The first arm of the command prints out the name of the branch `HEAD` points to, or silently fails. In the fail case, the second arm of the command prints out the commit that `HEAD` points to.